What is this bug on wood and paper?
I live in a Mediterranean climate and I often find these bugs in wooden furniture and sometimes around books. I would like to find the name and a solution to exterminate them.
The bug is black looks like this on a wooden kitchen utensil:

and the offspring seem white, and look like this on another kitchen utensil:

I squished an adult bug, let it dry, and put it under the microscope. The head looks like this:

The legs look like this:



If needed, I can try to get better microscope images.
I also took a video of them moving: here are the adult bug and the offspring.
I also sometimes hear a sound, like a small bug drilling into wood, but am not sure it belongs to this bug and haven't been able to record it.
What is this bug, and how can I eradicate it?

Very hard to say for sure - possibly a "book louse" or a mite (flour mite?) of some sort.

@bob1 Thanks! They look more like a flour mite than a book louse (it doesn't seem to have wings). I'll measure the size with a caliper next time I find one. Also, I tend to find them around ground condiments like cumin and sage. How can I be sure of the species?

It takes some expertise in ID to do so, you'd need clear pictures of various parts of the anatomy and a relevant reference with binomial key.

I'll see if I can get a better microscope for pictures. Where can I find a relevant reference or the binomial key? Do you suggest a better way to exterminate these insects?

A better picture isn't necessarily due to the microscope, though it does look like you have some chromatic and spherical aberation with that one. Better pictures would require better mounting and different illumination - a high-power dissecting scope would be better. I don't know where to find such a key - try the International Committee on Zoological Nomenclature for references. Best way to exterminate is to keep the whole area clean and dry.
